# How to build Internal Overviews with Python gdal BuildOverviews()?

Tags: python, gis, raster, gdal, qgis

Trying to mimic the result of running `gdaladdo -r average "D:\image.tif"` using python gdal bindings. When I run the code below, I get an external .ovr file. How can I generate an internal overview? Am I using the correct function to mimic gdaladdo?

```
from osgeo import gdal
InputImage = r"D:\image.tif"

Image = gdal.Open(InputImage,1)
Image.BuildOverviews("AVERAGE", [2,4,8,16,32,64])
```

I've also tried

```
Image = gdal.Open(InputImage, gdal.GA_Update)
```

Comment: Perhaps your image already contains internal overviews, in which case the driver will not force an overwrite and simply creates external overviews? Try running gdaladdo with the "-clean" option before running your script. You could also try compressing the overviews since your overviews may be too large to fit into a standard GeoTiff (hence why the BigTiff creation option was designed).

Comment: I checked, the image does not already have overviews on it. How would I compress the overviews? Is that a flag in Image.BuildOverviews()? The image I'm working with is 390 MB. I tried running on a totally different image and still it creates the external .OVR file.

Comment: Building overviews should not be a problem for a file of that size. In any case, to compress the overviews use: gdal.SetConfigOption('COMPRESS_OVERVIEW', 'DEFLATE') before building the overviews. An OS-related possibility is that you don't have user permissions to edit the file? Otherwise, I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: @Osian Gave that a try but no luck. I do have permissions on the file. Strange. Thanks for the ideas though.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
Image = gdal.Open('example.tiff', 1)
gdal.SetConfigOption("COMPRESS_OVERVIEW", "DEFLATE")
Image.BuildOverviews("AVERAGE", [2,4,8,16,32,64, 128, 256])
```